# how to explode bracket in string?

Tags: php

my code

```
$data = "{1,2,3}";
```

i need output

```
[
"1",
"2",
"3"
]
```

i use

```
$data = explode(',',$data);
```

But it comes with braces too

```
[
    "{1",
    "2",
    "3}"
]
```

Who has a way to remove braces Or is there a better way? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `substr()` to get only the string between the brackets.

```php
$data = explode(',', substr($data, 1, -1));
```

Comment: Another one `$data = explode(',', trim($data, '{}'));`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
//remove unused tag
$find = array("{", "}");
$replace = array("");
$data = "{1,2,3}";
$data = str_replace($find, $replace, $data);

//explode array
$data = explode(',',$data);
```